# Selenium 2 with Java : copy paste issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm working on Selenium Webdriver to develop a test project for my webapp using Java (Junit4).
I want to copy the row values from my webtable and paste them in an other row of the same table. I have tried this following code but it didn't work:

```
Actions duplicateBuilder= new Actions(driver);

WebElement s1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gridDonnee']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td")); 

Action Clicks1= duplicateBuilder.click(s1).build();

Clicks1.perform();

WebElement copyRow= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gridDonnee']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]"));

Action copys1= duplicateBuilder.sendKeys(copyRow,Keys.LEFT_CONTROL+ "c").build(); 

copys1.perform();

WebElement s4= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gridDonnee']/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td")); 

Action Clicks4= duplicateBuilder.click(s4).build();

Clicks4.perform();

Action pastes1= duplicateBuilder.sendKeys(copyRow,Keys.LEFT_CONTROL+ "v").build();  
pastes1.perform();
```

PS: I don't want to go for Js option as a solution. Please, anyone knows a better way to do it or proposes some modifications in my code to make it work ? 
Thanks !
Best Regards

Comment: Why not just `getText()` from one and `sendKeys()` to the other?

Comment: Hello! thanks for the idea . I could use that but the purpose of Selenium use is not to test the capabilities of Selenium doing my copy paste using it's core. The thing is I want to use Selenium webDriver to test the Js of my webapp's code; ( a function called behind the scenes each time I want to use the copy paste functionnality of the application. I hope I had clarified my issue and not complexified.